# Android Aarch64 emulator for app testing

Tags: android, android-ndk, emulation, arm64

I need to port some of my native android applications for Aarch64 (ARM64). I was trying to build those apps using Android ndk r14. But for testing I don't have platform. Does anyone here knows how to create emulator for Android Aarch64.

I went through below link,

https://www.linaro.org/blog/core-dump/running-64bit-android-l-qemu/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to find ant solution with this?